# Difference between Maring-left and padding-left

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering why these selectors produce same result

```css
#position2{
     margin-left:25px;
    }
    
#position3{
     padding-left:25px;
    }
```

```html
<h1 id="position2">Stackoverflow</h1>
<h1 id="position3">Stackoverflow</h1>
```

could any one explain major difference between these two properties

Comment: Shortest possible explanation: Padding adds space *within* the element, whereas Margin adds space *outside* of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

So the `margin` is added outside of the element you've targeted - in this instance it is placed to the left of the outside of the `#position2` div.

`padding`, on the other hand, is added *inside* the element you've targeted.  The easiest way to see this is by adding a background color to the code you've already got:

```
#position2{
        margin-left:25px;
        background-color: blue;
    }

#position3{
        padding-left:25px;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

This then outputs this, giving a clear visual representation of what's happening:
[image]